# Неправильно работает код python telebot

Tags: python, telebot

**в call.data не перемещается значение sub, хотя кнопку я нажимаю, что это может быть?**

```
    if call.data == 'ready':
    user_id = call.from_user.id

    global subscription
    subscription = False
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_next = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text= 'Подписался!', callback_data= 'sub')
    markup_inline.add(item_next)
    mess = f' Для Дальнейшего взаимодействия с ботом подпишитесь на наш канал! (ссылка)'
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, mess , parse_mode= 'html', reply_markup = markup_inline )

    if call.data == 'sub':
        print('1')
        result = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
        print(result)
        if result.status == 'member':
            subscription = True
            print('подписан')
        elif result.status == 'left':
            subscription = False
        else:
            subscription = True
```